# Cannot edit crontab as non root user

Tags: debian, permissions, cron

When I use the command `crontab -e` on my Debian server as a non root user (in this case as postgres), I can't edit it because of `"/tmp/crontab.SJlY0Y/crontab" [Permission Denied]`

`crontab -l` on the other hand works fine. How can I fix this problem?

Here are the current permissions:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/crontab.SJlY0Y/crontab
-rw------- 1 root postgres 1.2K Aug  3 11:44 /tmp/crontab.SJlY0Y/crontab
$ ls -l /var/spool/cron
total 12K
drwxrwx--T 2 daemon daemon  4.0K Sep 12  2012 atjobs
drwxrwx--T 2 daemon daemon  4.0K Jun  9  2012 atspool
drwx-wx--T 2 root   crontab 4.0K Aug  3 11:15 crontabs
$ ls -l /var/spool/cron/crontabs
total 12K
-rw------- 1 git      crontab 1.3K Mar  2 16:48 git
-rw------- 1 postgres crontab 1.4K Aug  3 11:15 postgres
-rw------- 1 root     root    2.3K Jul 20 20:32 root
$ ls -l /usr/bin/crontab
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 36K Jul  3  2012 /usr/bin/crontab
$ ls -ld /tmp/
drwxrwxrwt 6 root root 4.0K Aug  3 11:43 /tmp/
```

Comment: Looking at the permissions on ` /tmp/crontab.SJlY0Y/crontab ` I can see that the postgres group has no permission to read or write the file. Check the permissions on the crontab folder above it as well and run the following : chmod -R g+rw /tmp/crontab.SJlY0Y

Comment: The presence of `postgres` in `ls -l /tmp/crontab.SJlY0Y/crontab` is unexpected. Can you think of any reason why it should he there?

Comment: Since the crontab is for the postgres user, I was expecting the postgres user and group to own it, so that is why I'm suggesting that the group should have permission to read and write

Comment: @beans Sorry, I was not paying attention - didn't notice the user was postgres.

Comment: What is the permissions on your `/tmp` directory?  It should be `drwxrwxrwt`.

Comment: @beans The group shouldn't be allowed to access that file, otherwise another user in that group could view or modify the crontab. The permissions on the temporary file are correct, it's the ownership that's wrong: it should be owned by `postgres:crontab`. Since it's a temporary file, changing its permissions manually would be a one-time fix only; the solution requires finding why the ownership is wrong.

Comment: The man pages of crontab says that `su can confuse crontab`, and you're most likely logged into `postgres` using `su`. Can you try editing the crontab using `crontab -u postgres -e`? Also, are there other error lines than the `Permission Denied` you mentioned?

Comment: Re-installing crontab (as Gilles wrote) helped. When I look now at the permission of the file in /tmp it's seems to be correct: `drwx------ 2 postgres  crontab   4.0K Aug  4 03:21 crontab.gsOZJk`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> $ ls -l /usr/bin/crontab
> -rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 36K Jul  3  2012 /usr/bin/crontab
> ```

The ownership and permission should actually be

```
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root crontab 35880 Jul  3  2012 /usr/bin/crontab
```

Since Debian sarge, `crontab` is setgid crontab, not setuid root, as requested in [bug #18333](http://bugs.debian.org/18333).

This is the cause of your problem: the `crontab` program expects to run setgid, not setuid, so it creates the temporary file as the user and group it's running as, which are `root` and the caller's primary group instead of the calling user and the `crontab` group.

Reinstall the `cron` package:

```
apt-get --reinstall install cron
```

(as root). Check that `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` has the correct permissions and ownership:

```
drwx-wx--T 2 root crontab 4096 Oct  8  2013 /var/spool/cron/crontabs
```

In the future, don't mess with permissions of system files.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what caused this mess. I don't change permission of system files unless something is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot use `apt-get --reinstall install cron` because it gives back the following error:

```
gateway:/home/firewall# apt-get --reinstall install cron
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Suggested packages:
  anacron logrotate lockfile-progs checksecurity
Recommended packages:
  exim4 postfix mail-transport-agent
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cron
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/78.4kB of archives.
After unpacking 303kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 48768 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking cron (from .../cron_3.0pl1-100_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/cron_3.0pl1-100_i386.deb (--unpack):
 ***unable to make backup link of `./usr/bin/crontab' before installing new version: Operation not permitted***
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cron_3.0pl1-100_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
gateway:/home/firewall#
```

And if I try to erase the file manually it doesn't allow it either. How can I erase the file as it doesn't have permissions?

```
gateway:~# ls -la /usr/bin/crontab
---------- 1 root crontab 26380 Dec 20  2006 /usr/bin/crontab
```

Comment: Try using `sudo apt-get --reinstall install cron`